# Axiom Schema of Specification

Tags: set-theory

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)

> In the formal language of set theory, the axiom schema is:
>   $$\forall w_1,\ldots ,w_n\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\Leftrightarrow [x\in A\wedge \varphi(x,w_1,\ldots ,w_n,A)]).$$

It also emphasises that

> ... $B$ is not free in $\varphi$.

**Questions:** How to incorporate the above in the formalisation? And why does $A$ *have to be* free in $\varphi$?

Comment: The side condition that $B$ is not free in $\varphi$ is part of the formalization. It is already incorporated... not sure what you’re going for here.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Can you please show how it is a part of the formalisation?

Comment: Could you explain to me why you suspect it isn't? It is part of the definition of what an instance of the axiom scheme of specification is.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Don't we need to mention that none of $w_1,\ldots ,w_n$ can be $B$?

Comment: If any of the $w_i$ were $B$ and were also free in $\varphi$ then it would violate the condition that $B$ is not free in $\varphi.$ It is also customary that when we list a bunch of variables and call them by different names, that they are different variables. It is also customary to not write down formulas quantify twice over the same variable, though it's usually technically allowed.

Comment: What I'm asking is how to formalise this: $B$ is not free in $\varphi$? How to write it in formal first-order language?

Comment: We don't. It is a statement about the formula, not a statement in the formal language. (We could formalize the language we use to talk about formulas, but that's another thing entirely.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That clears things up! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$A$ does not *have to be free* in $\varphi$, but it is *allowed to be free* in $\varphi$. The notation $\varphi(x)$ means that $x$ is a variable that *could* occur freely in $\varphi$, but does not necessarily have to.

The better question is why $B$ is not allowed to be free in $\varphi$. This is to avoid the following contradiction:
\begin{align}
\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\leftrightarrow(x\in A\land x\notin B))
\end{align}